# Angular : Module not found error after creating a project

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, node-modules

I have wiped my computer clean and when I reinstalled Node and angular and created a new project using routing and CSS and when I run the command `ng serve` I get this error.

```
>>>ng serve
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names         |  Raw Size
vendor.js           | vendor        |   1.91 MB |
polyfills.js        | polyfills     | 109.52 kB |
main.js             | main          |  50.64 kB |
runtime.js          | runtime       |   6.34 kB |
styles.css          | styles        | 844 bytes |

                    | Initial Total |   2.07 MB

Build at: 2022-09-11T12:24:01.584Z - Hash: 2b9da3de59067827 - Time: 3310ms

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<PROJECT_PATH>/project/src/app/app.component.css?ngResource' in '<PROJECT_PATH>\project'

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<PROJECT_PATH>\project\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fng-cli-ws&logging=info&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=false&live-reload=true' in '<PROJECT_PATH>\project'

Error: The loader "<PROJECT_PATH>/project/src/app/app.component.css" didn't return a string.



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


× Failed to compile.
```

I've enabled Windows Subsystem for Linux and installed Ubuntu then installed node and angular, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below steps ::

1. Check if there is any issue related to npm version.
2. Try installing npm and angular cli globally.
3. Check environment path for ng module in system environment.
4. Restart cmd terminal and do npm install again.

Hope this will help.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: I'm using the version 16.17.0 and it seems this version doesn't have an issue like so. 
I've also tried to install angular locally and globally but the issue remains. 
the environment variables are good, I did npm install and the same issue remained. I've also removed node_modules folder and did npm_install then ng serve and the same issue is there.

Comment: Can you check path for the files which you are getting error , can you try removing import statement in .ts files and try adding it again, there might be chances that path can be wrong.
also there is some error related to web pack, can you try installing it explicitly ?

npm install webpack-dev-server -g

Comment: I have removed the "/app.component.css" from the ts that removes the first and last errors but when i add it back the errors comeback. 

I've tried reinstalling Webpack with the command you added but the error remained.